# How to filter an array of objects on the basis of another array of objects in swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, swift4

here is my  two array

```
 Arrayone = [{keyphraseId:"tcpid1234",name:"shakti"},{keyphraseId:"tcpid456",name:"shakti"},{keyphraseId:"tcpid897",name:"srichandan "},{keyphraseId:"tcpid779",name:"prakash"}]

Arraytwo  = [{idstring:"tcpid1234",name:"shakti"},{idstring:"tcpid456",name:"shakti"}]
```

i want to filter array one on the basis of array two i.e (i want to get all elements of array one which dont have is idstring   in array two

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind the O(n^2), then test directly in one step.

```
let arrayOne = [["keyphraseId":"tcpid1234", "name":"shakti"], ["keyphraseId":"tcpid456", "name":"shakti"], ["keyphraseId":"tcpid897", "name":"srichandan "], ["keyphraseId":"tcpid779", "name":"prakash"]]
let arrayTwo = [["idstring":"tcpid1234", "name":"shakti"],["idstring":"tcpid456", "name":"shakti"]]

arrayOne.filter { one in
    !arrayTwo.contains { two in
        one["keyphraseId"] == two["idstring"]
    }
}
```

If you want better performance O(n), drop `stringid`s into a set

```
let arrayOne = [["keyphraseId":"tcpid1234", "name":"shakti"], ["keyphraseId":"tcpid456", "name":"shakti"], ["keyphraseId":"tcpid897", "name":"srichandan "], ["keyphraseId":"tcpid779", "name":"prakash"]]
let arrayTwo  = [["idstring":"tcpid1234", "name":"shakti"],["idstring":"tcpid456", "name":"shakti"]]

let idstrings = Set(arrayTwo.flatMap { $0["idstring"] })

arrayOne.filter {
    guard let keyphraseId = $0["keyphraseId"] else { return false }
    return !idstrings.contains(keyphraseId)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You have 2 arrays as follows:**

```
    let arrayOne = [
        ["keyphraseId":"tcpid1234", "name":"shakti"],
        ["keyphraseId":"tcpid456", "name":"shakti"],
        ["keyphraseId":"tcpid897", "name":"srichandan "],
        ["keyphraseId":"tcpid779", "name":"prakash"]
    ]

    let arrayTwo  = [
        ["idstring":"tcpid1234", "name":"shakti"],
        ["idstring":"tcpid456", "name":"shakti"]
    ]
```

> To filter the array you need to follow 2 steps:
>
> 1. List out `idStrings` from `arrayTwo`
> 2. filter `arrayOne` with fetched `idString` from step 1

**To get elements from arrayOne**

**whose `keyphraseId` lies in arrayTwo as `idstring` :**

```
    let arrayTwoIds = arrayTwo.map { $0["idstring"] }
    let filteredResults = arrayOne.filter { arrayTwoIds.contains($0["keyphraseId"]) }
    print(filteredResults)
```

**whose `keyphraseId` not lies in arrayTwo as `idstring` :**

Just put `!` in filter condition:

```
    let filteredResults = arrayOne.filter { !arrayTwoIds.contains($0["keyphraseId"]) }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: He wants the elements in `Arrayone` that `Arraytwo` doesn't contain so the filter closure should be `!arrayTwoIds.contains($0["keyphraseId"])` instead

Comment: Thanks @Carpsen90, for pointing out it. I mislead the question somehow. :)